# Trying to inject factory inside a private function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

new to AngularJS here. I am trying to use a factory piece of code (logger)inside a private function as shown below, is that possible?
I am still trying to grasp the angular concepts. Thanks:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
    .module('app.admin')        
    .controller('UploadController', UploadController);     

    UploadController.$inject = ['$scope', 'FileUploader', 'dataservice', 'logger', 'config'];

    function UploadController($scope, FileUploader, dataservice, logger, config)
    {
      ...
      logger.info('blah blah blah', 'Error!');
      ...
      SomeFunction();
      ...
    }

    //private function
    function SomeFunction()
    {       
        //... code hidden for brevity

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            data: dataString,
            success: function(results) 
            {
                //need to use the 'logger' factory here   
                //logger.info('blah blah blah', 'Error!'); <= this wont work                            
            }            
        });
    }   

})();
```

Thank you

Comment: will regret using `$.ajax` when you should be using `$http`. You can update scope easier without extra work to notify angular to run digests

Comment: Why are you breaking that function out of the controller in the first place?

Comment: like i said  am new to angular and was just reusing the SomeFunction() from another developer :)

Comment: You aren't gaining anything ... and it;s easier to keep all the functions within one javascript scope. It is no more *private* outside the controller than it is inside it

Comment: once I get more comfortable with Angular I will refactor the code but for now I need to get this to work today so I am reusing the code. Thanks.

Comment: so...paste it inside controller and `logger` is available without doing anything else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function SomeFunction(logger)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        data: dataString,
        logger: logger,***************
        success: function(results) 
        {
            //need to use the 'logger' factory here   
            //logger.info('blah blah blah', 'Error!'); <= this wont work                            
        }            
    });
```

---

```
SomeFunction(logger);
```

Comment: that worked...weird I had tried that before and it was giving me errors. Go figure ...thanks!